# python in the function solve.QP for investment portfolio optimization, how do you set the constraint for long short strategy?

Tags: python, cvxopt

Let's say we have 6 assets `a b c d e f`,

we want to long `a b c d` and short `e f`, how to set the constraints by using the `solver.qp`?

I am using the

```
import cvxopt 
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set two inequality constraint each representing a min and max weight where the long will have min of 0 while the shorts will have a max of 0